# stage.loaderInfo.parameters works but LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters doesn't

Tags: actionscript-3

I am passing Flashvars in my game.html file.

MyClass is the Document class name for my game.swf

```
public class MyClass extends MovieClip {
  public function MyClass() {
    loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _Init);
  }

  public function _Init(e:Event) {
    var parameters:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
    // There is nothing in parameters object.
  }
}
```

My game.fla contains various layers on the main timeline. I have another game which has only one layer and that game loads the parameters correctly. I am finding this very strange.

Note:

1. trace root.name in the above code -> instance8 (there are 8 layers in the time line)
2. trace root.name in the other game (in which flashvars is working) -> root1 is the traced output

Am I missing something very basic here?

**Solved this but couldn't understand the reason**

So, I changed the line

```
var parameters:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

to

```
var parameters:Object = stage.loaderInfo.parameters;
```

Why did the first approach didn't work?

Comment: is one game loading the other?  I ran this code in an action script project in FB 4.6 and it worked fine, both types.